# Where does "Label" field value come from in MobileFirst Application Center for APK file

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm uploading APK file with Ant task and want to set certain Label for application in the Application center, however I'm still getting the same label.

I tried following:

- set android:label from my activity in AndroidManifest.xml
- change project name in build.xml (for Android native app)

None of these have any impact on the Label

MFPF version is 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change it in Values strings.xml

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was changing android:label of <activity> but not of <application>